# Is there a way to check whether the "APIs and services" are enabled to a project in google cloud platform via API call?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to check for a project whether the "API and services" are enabled or not via an API call.

Answer (score 3):

You can list enabled and disabled Apis and services by calling the services.list method using the curl command.

If you want to list enabled APIs and services, run the following:

gcurl https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[Project_Number]/services?filter=state:ENABLED

To list the disabled APIs and services, run:

gcurl https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[Project_Number]/services?filter=state:DISABLED

You can read more about the different ways of checking APIs and services [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods). You can also learn more about the "services.list" method [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list) as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to check whether a particular API is enabled using the Python API, this snippet of code should help:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

project = "your-project-id"
api_name = "compute" # API name

service = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1')
request = service.services().get(
    name=f"projects/{project}/services/{api_name}.googleapis.com"
)
response = request.execute()

if response.get('state') == 'DISABLED':
    # Do something
```

Comment: Don't you need to call (nice to have) `service.close()`
near the end according to https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md#build-the-service-object?

Comment: @VincentYin - sure. This was just a code fragment to show how. I wasn't thinking about wrapping it all up cleanly in this snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also just encountered and then wrote up this quirk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047799/13676217